# React-native Callback get props of child navigator from parent

Tags: react-native, navigator

I'm trying to access route.id of my Navigator from his parent container to be able to hide/show a  depending on Navigators route.id

I believe child to parent communications would need a callback function, here is my attempt.

```
var Home = require('./Home');
var Navigation = require('./Navigation');

class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.appContainer}>
                <Navigation getNavigator={this.getNavigator.bind(this)}/>
                <Footer />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the child component

```
var _navigator; 

class Navigation extends Component {
    getNavigator(route){
        return this.refs.navigator.push(route);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            ref={(navigator) => { this.navigator = navigator; }}
            initialRoute={{
                    id: 'Home',
                    index:0,
                }}
            renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}
            configureScene={(route) => {
                if (route.sceneConfig) {
                    return route.sceneConfig;
                }
                return Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight;
            }}
            navigationBar={
                <NavigationBar
                style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f6f8'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
            }
            />
        );
    }
    navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
        _navigator = navigator;
        switch (route.id) {
            case 'Home':
                return (<Home navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps}  title="Home" />);
                ...     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you may not have two `this` in a method. You bind the `this` from the parent, so `this` within `getNavigator` is the `this` from the parent. In this `this` no `refs.navigator` exists, this is why it doesn't work.

The way you would normally implement is having the Navigator as the top most component and passing a `navigateTo` method in the props of the children (or the context). If you would still like to navigate from the parent in the child you have two options:

1. Add redux and have a route store, the parent dispatches an action, that the child fulfils in the `componentDidReceiveProps` method.
2. You may add methods to be called from a ref of your navigator component. This would be similar to the approach used in DrawerLayoutAndroid. You may have a look at the React Native implementation to see how that works, or [you may look at the polyfill here.](https://github.com/iodine/react-native-drawer-layout/blob/master/src/DrawerLayout.ios.js#L174-182)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to obtain a reference to the navigator object in the context that instantiates the component, without the use of a callback to set it manually.

Include a "ref" property in your navigator like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Navigator
                ref="mainNavigator"
                initialRoute={initialStack[0]}
                renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)} />
            </View>
        );
}
```

Access it later in relevant functions via the component's refs property:

```
componentDidMount() {
    alert(this.refs.mainNavigator); // [Object] [object]
}
```